# Using 'browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest' In the DevTools console returns an error

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

```
function logURL(requestDetails) {
    console.log(`The URL is: ${requestDetails.url}`);
 }
browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(logURL, {urls: ["<all_urls>"],});
```

Loading the above code as part of an extension (placed inside a `background.js` file), works just fine, I can see the logs in the Browser Console but not in the Dev Tools Console.

If I open another Firefox profile with no extensions loaded in it, and paste the following in the Dev Tools Console:

```
function logURL(requestDetails) {
    console.log(`The URL is: ${requestDetails.url}`);
 }
browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(logURL, {urls: ["<all_urls>"],});
```

I get an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: webRequest is not defined
    <anonymous> debugger eval code:5
debugger eval code:5:1
    <anonymous> debugger eval code:5
```

Why is that? Are the Browser Console and the Dev Tools Console not using the same JS code?